# Are we living in a Universe with 3 time dimensions and 1 spatial dimension?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

If I said that we are living in a Universe with 3 time dimensions and 1 spatial dimension, would I be wrong?

By that I mean if the spacetime interval was evaluated as `-time1^2-time2^2-time3^2+space1^2` instead of `space1^2+space2^2+space3^2-time1^2`.

Is there an absolute difference between a spatial and a time dimension, or are they like the positive and negative electrical charges?

**Edit:** This came to me after reading a question considering more than 1 time dimensions. I think it was about a 2+2 universe, which prompted the question "Which 2 would be the time dimensions?"

So I guess the real questions is, is time's property the fact that it is a single dimension of its type/sign, instead of 3? Could we talk about spacetimes only for 1+N pseudo-euclidean spaces, but not for M+N where M>1 and N>1?

And also, if we have 3 time dimensions and 1 space dimension, and the spacetime interval was

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10651/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43322/2451 , and links therein.

Comment: We actually have no idea what "time" is or how it could be defined. So *time* is just a word. However, there are some concepts that we relate to time, e.g. the direction of increasing entropy, that you would have to refine in your claim.

Comment: @Clever To clarify, in a 2+2 Minkowski spacetime which 2 dimensions would you call space?

Comment: I guess it would be difficult to read your question if he had one spatial dimension only...

Comment: @AndreHolzner But then the time dimensions would play the role of the space dimensions :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [More than one time dimension](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43630/)

Comment: @sashoalm: I think that the term "time" we attribute to one dimension is exactly this: a term for *one* dimension. The fact that in SR time and space dimensions are mixed, states that *time* is no so special after all. I think a lot of terminology would be messed up in a 2+2 world (e.g. time-like and space-like and therefore light-like and probably *causality* ...).

Answer (score 2):

Time-like dimensions are those where motion is only possible in one direction (we call that forward because it's pessimistic to say you can only go backward) and observing is only possible in the reverse direction (that's a direct result of motion only being allowed in one direction). Spatial dimensions are those where motion is possible in both directions as is observation.

The spacetime interval can be written with either the mostly plus or the mostly minus signature, (+ - - -) or (- + + +), without changing the fact that there is only one time dimension and three spatial dimensions.

When you see something like "in an m+n universe", m is the number of spatial dimensions and n is the number of temporal dimensions.

Comment: I think you should be very careful with that first paragraph. Human experience is that the **flow of time** is unidirectional, but the human view of the flow of time has no obvious significance in GR.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not talking about human view. A null path can move in either direction for spatial dimensions but a null path only moves in one direction for temporal dimensions. GR describes this well. That is why we say spatial dimensions become time-like beyond the event horizon of a black hole; null paths (and thus, any other applicable path) are only defined for one direction beyond the event horizon.

Comment: Null geodesics don't *move* at all. They are just curves in spacetime.

Comment: @JohnRennie And also a point particle is really a line in space-time, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @sashoalm: the worldline of a point particle is a line

Comment: @JohnRennie Forgive me, I'm not the best with terminology and wording. But the point remains valid. Motion is only possible in one direction for temporal dimensions. Were motion possible in both directions, information from times ahead of an observer could travel backwards and be observed at earlier times. Since only one direction of motion is possible, information can only reach an observer by moving forward, and thus only the past is observable. Similarly, spatial dimension allow motion in both directions, so information can be observed coming from both directions

Comment: GR describes this in geodesic motion by using a path element (usually $\lambda$) to represent an increment of motion along the geodesic. We find that even null geodesics follow the path element in a direction of non-decreasing time. Any results to the contrary usually violate causality and are summarily classified as non-physical