# How everything will act in a universe of two time dimensions?

Tags: spacetime, time, spacetime-dimensions

As far as we know, we live in a universe with one and single dimension of time, we know that some events happens BEFORE or AFTER other events, we know that some events happens slower or faster then others, but that is with a single dimension of time, what about another universe of two time dimensions, how will events be synchronized...

I don't think there will be the terms before and after anymore in that universe, because as an analogy, we can order real numbers but we can't do the same with complex numbers ( two axes ) but the terms slower and faster are probably still valid, because length is measurable in any number of dimensions, ( duration is length in time dimension ).

Note here that many strange phenomenon will be introduced, like time rotation! also, events around event in time => events in distance R around it  in a circle, also time projection seems very strange, and linear functions in time plan.

Can any of you imagine such universe? and how particle will interact...?

**UPDATE 1 :**

We can't answer this question , we still dont even understand our one time demension universe , we can only only guess , improve , relate , note , motivate , add refrences  ...

Motivation :

Maybe quantum physics is probabilistic becuase there are more than one time dimensions making the computation  maybe those two or more axes are synchronized enough on the macroscopic level but not so exact to reach the precision of the microscopic level

Comment: "Can any of you imagine such universe ?" - Definitely not.

Comment: Do you understand the "one dimension of time" that we (assumedly) have?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43322/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43630/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuition for multiple temporal dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q43322)