# Is time really a 1-dimensional object that we only traverse through?

Tags: spacetime, time, universe, spacetime-dimensions

Is time really a 1-dimensional object that we traverse || is it possible that time can also be traversed horizontally.  I think the later would also put it on a 2 dimensional plane.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)

Comment: i don't think so.  This is specific to the dimension and (flow as a minor secondary)  of time not the flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one time dimension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43630)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43322/25301

Comment: What do you mean by "object?" This "object" would have to be present in every place where physical processes happen, right? In other words, this time object would have to fill all of space. How is that effectively different from conventional ideas of [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime)?

Comment: @jameslarge exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time is one of the four dimensions of spacetime; you are traversing time at the rate of one second per second even while you are standing still.

Under Special Relativity you can travel back and forth at will in the three spatial dimensions (such back and forth across a room, or up and down the stairs), but you are forever stuck going forward in time at a constant rate, the rate of time progression as given by your own wristwatch.