# Are extra dimensions timelike or spacelike?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, metric-tensor, causality, compactification

In special relativity there is a clear difference between spatial and temporal dimensions of spacetime due to the Minkowski metric diag(-1,1,1,1). In higher dimensional theories (10- and 26-dimensional string theories) does this asymmetry continue with additional dimensions being specifically time- or space-like or is there no clear difference?

Comment: related or possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43322/intuition-for-multiple-temporal-dimensions https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43630/more-than-one-time-dimension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Polchinski's *String Theory*, Chapter 1:

> We want to study the classical and quantum dynamics of a one-dimensional object, a string.  The string moves in $D$ flat spacetime dimensions, with metric $\eta_{\mu \nu} = \mathrm{diag}(-,+,+,\cdots,+)$.

So all additional dimensions are spacelike.

Strictly speaking Polchinski is only talking about bosonic string theory at this point, but I believe the same applies to superstring theories as well.  (It's been a long time since I thought about this in any detail.)

Comment: This tells us that the answer is X, but it doesn't tell us *why* the answer is X.

Comment: @BenCrowell:  Nor did the question ask why the answer was X.  ;-)

Comment: This answer also suggests that the answer is not necessarily what you claim: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43637/4552 . The only way to clear this up and learn something would be to understand the whys, rather than just quoting Aristotle as an authority.

Comment: @BenCrowell:  That's a fair perspective, and if someone wants to write an answer explaining the whys, I'll happily upvote it.  Mainly I wanted to ensure that the question didn't go unanswered, since the question seemed to be asking for a specific answer in the context of string theory.