# Why can't the metric have more than one timelike coordinate?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, time, spacetime-dimensions

In one of his lectures, L Susskind stated that he cannot make sense of a metric with more than one timelike dimension. I also have trouble imagining it, but is there a good mathematical or physical reason why this is not possible?

Let us assume all extra timelike dimensions are compactified, so we cannot directly observe them. What kind of trouble or unphysical problems would this create? I am not asking for non-standard physics here, but just a more formal reason than intuition as to why we assume the extra dimensions are necessarily spatial (I have a basic understanding of why string theory needs extra spatial dimensions, but I do not understand if it forbides extra time dimensions). The question is not limited to string theory though.

Comment: You should link the lecture in order to avoid collecting downvotes, since it would be easier to answer the question if we could check your source.

Comment: Relevant, though speculative:  [Double Plus, Double Minus: A Gentle Introduction to the Physics of *Dichronauts*](https://www.gregegan.net/DICHRONAUTS/00/DPDM.html), by Greg Egan

Comment: @Yukterez thanks, I will try to find it, I saw it a while ago though. He talked about it  because someone in the audience asked about it and he seemed really pissed off, as if the question was just scifi material.

Comment: Related, although not from the relativistic but the quantum perspective: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoJ5BRghuAk&t=156s

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43322/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43630/2451 and links therein.